# vboxmanage import not showing in VirtualBox Manager GUI

Tags: virtualbox

VBoxManage startvm "centos-minimal" --type headless does the job getting a headless vm. Is there a way to interact "centos-minimal" using VirtualBox Manager GUI?

Comment: Have you set the *"Virtual Machines Folder"* in *Preferences* on the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to the settings of your VM and add shared folder:
[image]

After this start your VM and install Guest Additions.
[image]

**You will now be able to transfer files between host an guest.**